# Can I use a text file as my database in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, text-files

I would like to use a delimited text file (xml/csv etc) as a replacement for a database within Ruby on Rails.  Solutions?

(This is a class project requirement, I would much rather use a database if I had the choice.)

I'm fine serializing the data and sending it to the text file myself.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the class project, either your Prof/Teacher has completely misunderstood the purpose of Rails or you are trying to use Rails to do a simple Ruby project that requires you to do file read/writes to store simple data.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is probably to take the ActiveModel API and build your methods that parse your files in the appropriate ways.

Here's a good [presentation](http://confreaks.net/videos/283-lsrc2010-rails-next-top-model-using-activemodel-and-activerelation) about ActiveModel and ActiveRelation where he builds a custom model, which should have a lot of similar concepts (but different backend.) And also a good [blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) by Yehuda about the ActiveModel API

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? It is much better solution.

- It uses a single file.
- It is way faster than doing the serialization yourself.
- It is zero configuration. Very simple to use.
- You get ACID compliance, transactions sub selects etc etc.

Comment: The human readable text file is a requirement for the project.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a way to store tables in [CSV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/csv-storage-engine.html).  It has some pretty serious limitations, but it sounds like your requirements demand something with some pretty serious limitations anyway.

I've never set up a Rails project that way, and I don't know what it would take, but it seems like it might be possible.

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) seems to work by storing data on disk as a SQL script that creates your database.  It records changes in memory and a log file, and when you shut down it recreates a single SQL script again.  I've not used this one myself.

HSQLDB doesn't appear to be one of the supported databases in Rails.  I don't know what it would take to add support for a new database.